# Wordpress - Extending partly transparent header images above wrapper

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Platform: Wordpress (self-hosted)
Template: TwentyTen

I've been able to work out most things by Googling or tinkering around with familiar parts of the stylesheet, but I'm stuck now and am hoping someone can help me out. Basically, I’d like to create a header that is similar to this in design (http://albertaspeechie.blogspot.com) in that part of the header background will be transparent.

If I create an image with a transparent section, it shows as white because it's still within the header/wrapper with its white background.

I'm thinking that, possibly, setting the header background as transparent (though I can't figure out how to just make the header transparent, without affecting the rest of the wrapper) and boosting the padding above the wrapper. and increasing the height of the header. I used to know how to increase the height of the header, but I can't seem to find it anywhere anymore.

Any advice as to how I could do this? I'm only bumbling around with a test blog at the moment, so there's no published site to show. It's just a straight twentyten at the moment, without any adjustments until I can figure out how to do a partly  transparent header.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I'm not sure why people are downvoting this. I've followed the rules and instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use positioning to move the image outside the header.

1. Add the image you want to use to inside your header. Make sure the image has a transparent background - use a png file for example.
2. Add `position: relative` to the header
3. Add `position: absolute` to the image, and then provide coordinates for the image.

To position it outside the header, provide a negative value for `top`. To center the image add 0 to `left` and `right`, and then use `margin: auto.`

```
.header img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: lightblue;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.header {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.header img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/pRgxrj)

Read more about positioning [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, ovokuro.